# If $U \sim \operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$, why is $F(a) = a$ for arbitrary $a \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: probability

Let $U \sim \operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$ be a random variable. Then the cdc $F$ of $U$ is

$$
F(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad x < 0 \\
            x & \quad 0 \leq x < 1\\
            1 & \quad x\geq 1
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

The other day my professor mentioned that for all $a \in (-\infty,\infty)$, we have

$$F(a) = a$$

But I don't see how this is true. If $a < 0$, then $F(a) = 0$, and if $a \geq 1$, we have $F(a) = 1$. It's only when $0 < a < 1$ that we have $F(a) = a$.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, because it definitely does not seem that $F(a) = a$ is true for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it's only for $a$ in $[0,1]$. You either misheard your professor or they were wrong.

Comment: With that being said, suppose I wanted to show that $1-U$ has the same distribution as $U$. Clearly, if $a$ is an arbitrary real number, I want to show that $F_U(a) = F_{1-U}(a)$. From your answer, I would have to consider three cases on $a$. Is there a simpler way?